# .NET Reading windows security event log and expand replacement strings

Tags: vb.net, security, event-log

Running on Windows 7 and Server 2012, I have a VB.NET app that uses the System.Diagnostics.EventLog collection of log entries.  When I retrieve one particular Security event log entry's Message property I have a bunch of text that looks like "%%2048" instead of something like "Account Enabled".  See the snippet below:

> User Account Control:
>       %%2048

From what I have discovered, this may be a "replacement string" that is a kind of place holder for another string.  This is new to me and I would like to know how to translate these codes into their final value.  When I use the Event Viewer application the final text ("Account Enabled") is visible instead of the numeric equivalent so I know that the translation is possible.

I have seen some posts that talk about using a different class (EventLogRecord) but I have not seen enough that helps me.  Can anyone provide an example of how to get a properly formatted event log entry message?

Comment: A quick Google search yielded me this that may be of use **https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/814564**

Comment: Also could you show what you have done; ***it may be in your code***

Comment: Are you getting some of the logs from a remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

I wound up trying out the EventLogRecord class.  Using the FormatDescription method gave me the properly formatted event message body I was hoping for.  It just took quite a bit of trial and error to figure out how to use this class as well as how to format a very basic EventLogQuery string (I was trying to avoid using a query string).  The only examples I saw of a query string were very complex (to me) and I just wanted a plain old select all records with no filtering.  Fortunately, it only took a couple of tries to stumble upon the right brief syntax.

From what I can tell, the old method worked fine for Win XP and Server 2003 (the OS's that the application had been running on).  I am now porting it to Windows 7/Server 2012 and apparently the OS has started using the placeholders in the message body in the newer OS's.  The EventLogRecord is specifically for these newer OS versions and as such has the features you need to format the message properly.